# Fault tolerant log management tool

Tags: logging, logstash, microservices, elastic-stack

Is Logstash fault-tolerant and reliable for centralized logging of microservice architecture? Are there any open source alternatives to achieve fault tolerance?

Comment: I have gone through a couple of posts that says Logstash should be used in conjunction with message brokers such as Kafka, RabbitMQ, etc to make it fault-tolerant but others have commented that this approach has drawbacks. The drawback is processing logs that are already processed when the logstash instance gets re-started for some reason.

Comment: Try Kafka, never had any problems with processing old messages. [This blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/just-enough-kafka-for-the-elastic-stack-part1) explains a little about using kafka with elastic stack, it's kind old, but it is still a good starting point.